# Determining API Product (having same API proxy) quota value when associated with same App

Tags: apigee

Scenario:
At Apigee Edge platform, A single App is associated with two API products where both products are associated with same API proxy. Differences among these API products are in product quota value and scope.

In the above scenario, request is coming with a specified scope. Is it possible that Edge platform use the quota value of the product having scope as specified in the request?

Based on my testing, quota value is picked from any one of these two products and so not able to enforce the quota value.

My understanding is as API proxy is same in both API products; quota values determined at run-time can be quota value of any one of these two products and that means quota values may not be enforced as required. So in such scenarios, possible solution is to assign same quota value to both products. Please confirm.

As scopes are different for both API products, is there a way to identify an API product based on scope and then fetch corresponding quota values? Any inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My understanding is as API proxy is same in both API products; quota values determined at run-time can be quota value of any one of these two products and that means quota values may not be enforced as required. So in such scenarios, possible solution is to assign same quota value to both products. Please confirm.

Yes, you can assign the same quota value to both products.  As a side note, it's worth noting that quota counters are maintained at the policy-name-level per API bundle.  More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21615609/quota-counters-what-makes-them-distinct-are-there-additional-filters-on-top-o).

> As scopes are different for both API products, is there a way to identify an API product based on scope and then fetch corresponding quota values? Any inputs.

This would not work. The scope field in the UI allows you to assign both a default value and allow what scopes can be attached to a token in an OAuth proxy.  In other words, the scope is modified by the Product(s), not the other way around.

Instead, I propose you to avoid Products for quota references at all.  You could use [Key/Value Map](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/persist-data-using-keyvaluemap) or hard-code the quota values in reference variables within the API proxy.  The former allows flexibility without deployment, while the latter is faster.  Both will allow you to set a quota value, but without the unnecessary plumbing from using scopes.  This won't allow an admin to update the quota values via the UI, but these are alternatives if you must to use 2 API Products that are associated with the same API proxy.

> In the above scenario, request is coming with a specified scope. Is it possible that Edge platform use the quota value of the product having scope as specified in the request?

It's not possible because you are attempting to use scope as input to sway Apigee Edge's decision on Product, but Edge does not work that way.  Apigee Edge decides the product(s), then adjusts the scope accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Each `Product` can be assigned its own quota. Document Reference: http://apigee.com/docs/api/create-api-product

snippet:

```
quota           The number of request messages permitted by this API product.
quotaInterval   The time interval over which the number of request messages is calculated.
quotaTimeUnit   The time unit defined for the quotaInterval
```