# Apigee Spike Arrest Rate Limit Application

Tags: api, backend, apigee, throttling

I am an Apigee newbie.

I am trying to understand the Spike Arrest policy.

I am looking at this documentation:

http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/shield-apis-using-spikearrest

http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/policy-attachment-and-enforcement

The one thing I cannot understand for certain is if, when the Spike Arrest Policy is applied to an ApiProxy, whether the rate limit is applied per Key/Client Dev Application, or is it shared between all Keys/Client Dev Applications?

For example if we have the following config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <SpikeArrest async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="spikearrest-1">
  <DisplayName>SpikeArrest-1</DisplayName>
  <FaultRules/>
  <Properties/>
  <Identifier ref="request.header.some-header-name"/>
  <MessageWeight ref="request.header.weight"/>
  <Rate>50ps</Rate>
</SpikeArrest>
```

And Client Dev Apps:
`1. DevApp1`
`2. DevApp2`

Is the 50ps rate limit shared between `DevApp1` and `DevApp2`, or do `DevApp1` and `DevApp2` get 50ps rate limit each?

Thanks,

Comment: As per link below, count is maintained per API bundle, per policy name. Which means counts will not be shared accross bundles even if the identifier is the same. Please take a look at this answer for further details. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21614059/apigee-spike-arrest-applies-to-each-api-bundle-or-all-api-bundles/21716886#21716886. So, your scenario below shouldn't be a problem, since count is independent.

Comment: Thanks @Diego! I currently have this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912316/apigee-spikearrest-behavior In our organisation we have 6 MessageProcessors(MP) and I assume they are working in a strictly round robin. If I have a rate of 3pm, which means 1 hit each 20sec, instead of 1 successful hit every 20sec I get 6 successful ones in the range of 20sec and then the spikearrest error, meaning it hit once each MP. This means I get 6 per 20 sec instead of 1. Is there any way to sync the spikearrests across the MPs? ConcurrentRatelimit doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any of the predefined variables:
http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/api/variables-reference

The variable that is probably the most commonly used for Spike Arrest is `client.ip`.
Edge will make all elements of a request message available. If your clients are adding a client_id (aka API key) to a request as a query parameter, for example `api.call.com?client_id=u34r8ur`, then you would set the variable in your Spike Arrest Identifier to be:

`<Identifier ref="request.queryparam.client_id"/>`

Or if it is in an HTTP header:

`<Identifier ref="request.header.client_id"/>`

Hope that helps!

Comment: For completeness, if you wanted to use `client.ip`, you'd use:   `<Identifier ref="client.ip"/>`

Comment: that was extremely helpful, especially the example with weather it's a queryparam or header! Thanks I appreciate it! What I am still unable to find out is how to do it conditional at the proxy endpoint. For example I want App1 to have 5ps, App2 - 5ps, App3 - 1ps, App4 - 2ps - all of these on the Proxy Endpoint. If I just have the 25ps then App2 for example can consume all of it and make the resource unavailable for the rest of them and I want to avoid this. Do you know if there is a way I can do this?

Comment: Can you describe a t higher level what your requirements are? It may make more sense for you to use another approach, such as Quota, if your goal is to control consumption.

Comment: Thanks! But I do need a SpikeArrest. I currently have this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912316/apigee-spikearrest-behavior In our organisation we have 6 MessageProcessors(MP) and I assume they are working in a strictly round robin. If I have a rate of 3pm, which means 1 hit each 20sec, instead of 1 successful hit every 20sec I get 6 successful ones in the range of 20sec and then the spikearrest error, meaning it hit once each MP. This means I get 6 per 20 sec instead of 1. Is there any way to sync the spikearrests across the MPs? ConcurrentRatelimit doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1):

Its [per app](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/rate-limit-api-traffic-using-quota#identifying-apps) identified by your identifier.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply @Srikanth! So at the moment we have the default setting "<Identifier ref="request.header.some-header-name"/>". Does that do anything at all at the moment, does it work? Or do I need to set something else rather than "request.header.some-header-name", for example "request.header.client_id"? I am asking this as "some-header-name" looks like a place holder to me rather than an actual variable. Also what's the effect/behaviour of "some-header-name", does it do anything at all?

Comment: The identifier is the way of identifying the app. It is key to rate limiting.

Comment: Atanas, 'request.header.some-header-name' isn't functional--it is just an attempt to indicate that you can put any variable (pre-defined or custom) that meets your requirements. We'll update the doc to make that clearer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @ap-andrew! So which one is functional? I am looking at the Variables reference, to try and determine what to use? I don't see "client_id" specified in there, is that also not functional?